# How to keep an activity indicator moving in a for-loop

Tags: android, for-loop, titanium, appcelerator

I have an activity indicator in my app, which I show when I'm processing quite a lot of data (building table rows) in a for-loop.

However while in the loop, the indicator doesn't move at all. Probably because the loop uses all resources.

Do I need to put a kind of 'sleep' in the loop so the indicator can redraw, or is there any other solution?

I'm using Titanium sdk 6+, the app is written with Android in mind.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can use async task to process such resource intensive work and you can override `onProgressUpdate` to update your dialog at same time.

Comment: Does the activity Indicator ever move? Have you seen it working?

Comment: it sounds like you're doing to much work in the loop. Are you adding rows dynamically or are you adding them all at once?

Comment: Yes, the indicator shows, and it moves for a (very) short time, then it stops.

Comment: By async task you mean use setTimeout?

Comment: In the loop I build an array with all the table rows and after that, I use table.setData to put them in the .

Answer (score 2):

Actually, here you are doing 2 different UI tasks on one & only 1 UI Thread.

**UI Task 1: Showing indicator**

**UI Task 2: Showing table rows.**

But there's only 1 UI thread which we call as Main UI Thread. So doing 2 tasks on same thread will keep hanging up 2 tasks interchangeably which is why you see indicator moving sometimes after a freeze.

Ideally, it doesn't take much time to create any UI with today's processors so that you need to display indicator while doing them.

If you still think that your UI is taking lot of time in building up, then I would suggest you to choose another structure to create rows because as per my experience, creating 100 rows similar to Twitter Tweets on an average device will only take 2-3 seconds if built up properly.

That's why you really need to consider redesigning the Row UI creation code & it's strictly not recommended to show indicator on UI tasks.

To help you more, share some code snippets of how you are creating rows & what type of UI elements you're filling in them.

Comment: 2-3 seconds is a LONG time for UI building, can be much much faster (within a second), even on slower devices. For the rest I fully agree ;)

Comment: Yeah, it's a long time due to many UI elements in a single row. That's why it's always preferable to create rows in lazy loading manner.

Comment: Sometimes lazy loading implementation takes lot of coding, so another lazy alternate, which is not recommended but works very well, is to create rows in batches.. e.g., If you have 100 rows to create, create 20 initially, then create rest after a timeout, like next 40 rows in a timeout of 2-3 seconds & so on. It gives time to prepare UI as the user is busy in looking UI for few seconds.

Comment: Yes, I think that will be my way to go! The user doesn't see the table immediately so In have time toch creatie the rows in a 'lazy' manner. Thanks for the tips!